# Relationship for $\log(A_1+A_2+\cdots+\cdots+A_n)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

It's a very well know fact that
$$
\log\left(\prod_{i=1}^n A_i\right)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\log(A_i)
$$

Can we say anything about 
$$
\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^n A_i\right)=\text{ ????}
$$

My question is whether we can put a sum(or maybe product) somehow outside????

Comment: -1 for not checking wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Summation.2Fsubtraction

Comment: From $\uparrow$ $$
    \log _b \sum\limits_{i=0}^N a_i = \log_b a_0 + \log_b \left( 1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^N \frac{a_i}{a_0} \right) = \log _b a_0 + \log_b \left( 1+\sum\limits_{i=1}^N b^{\left( \log_b a_i - \log _b a_0 \right)} \right). $$

Comment: Thanks. Guys. But that is not what I want. I guess it's my fault for not stating it properly. see my modifications.

Comment: I am really puzzled by the downvotes on this question, which seems perfectly legitimate to me.

Comment: @MJD Thank you. The idea is I am trying to simplify an expression that has a sum inside the log. I was wondering if I can re-write it in some other way. Of course I know that I can't bring the sum out. I was interested in whether I can express it in some other way.